# How to view, find and remove key value pairs in CFMutable Dictionary

Tags: objective-c

How do i find and remove the key value pairs of a particular key using CFMutableDictionaryRef.
I have added a value using CFMutableDictionary but i need to know how to search ,view and delete a keyvalue pair.
The value i have created is a structure pointer and key is an integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beata,

The CFMutableDictionaryRef documentation shown [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html) will guide you.

In the order of your question:

For finding an element, see `CFDictionaryGetValue`

For removing an element, see `CFDictionaryRemoveValue`

Note that the CFDictionary types are a 'toll-free-bridge' with NSDictionary.

Frank